# How to get PlainText or Html Text using AE.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#, email, pop3

I'm trying to get Plain Text or HTML Text of email using AE.Net.Mail.
I cannot find any documentation.

```
using (Pop3Client pop3 = new AE.Net.Mail.Pop3Client("pop3Server", "login", "pwd", 995, true))
{
   for (var i = pop3.GetMessageCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      MailMessage Msg = pop3.GetMessage(i);
      string HtmlText = Msg.??????
      string PlainText = Msg.??????                
   }
}
```

Edit : I found this solution

```
   IList<Attachment> iList;
   string HtmlText = "", PlainText = "";

   for (var i = pop3.GetMessageCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      MailMessage msg = pop3.GetMessage(i);
      TextBody = msg.Body;
      iList = msg.AlternateViews as IList<Attachment>;
      if (iList.Count == 0) iList = msg.Attachments as IList<Attachment>;
      if (iList.Count > 0)
      {
           TextBody = iList[0].Body;
           HtmlBody = iList[1].Body;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem with this method:

Firt create a class:

```
    class BodyContent
  {
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
  }
```

Than:

```
List<BodyContent> bodies = new List<BodyContent>();
  foreach (AE.Net.Mail.Attachment item in mail.AlternateViews)
  {
    bodies.Add(new BodyContent
    {
      ContentType = item.ContentType,
      Body = item.Body
    });
  }
```

And check has "text/html":

```
string body="";
      BodyContent bodyTemp= bodies.Find(x => x.ContentType == "text/html");
      if (bodyTemp== null)
        body = mail.Body;
      else
        body = bodyTemp.Body;
```

And if has "text/html", body's format html else body's format plain

Answer (score 2):

Body = e.Value.AlternateViews.GetHtmlView().Body,

Answer (score 0):

If your `MailMessage` is the `System.Net.Mail` one, you can get the message body from the [`Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body) property. It may be either HTML or plain-text depending on the `IsBodyHtml` property. The `AlternateViews` property may also contain alternate forms of the message body.

Comment: In AE.Net.Mail, no `IsBodyHtml` property. For allmessage in the `Body` property, I have the plain-text of message.

For one message there is 2 `AlternateViews` :
  [0] with `ContentType` "texte/plain"
  [1] with `ContentType` "texte/html"

For other message there is no `AlternateViews` but 2 `Attachements`
  [0] with `ContentType` "texte/plain"
  [1] with `ContentType` "texte/html"

And for others message  there is no `AlternateView`s and no `Attachements`.

How can i obtain html text ?

Comment: You may obtain the HTML body from the `AlternateView` whose `ContentType` is `"text/plain"`; you might need to read it from the `ContentStream`.

Comment: There is not `ContentStream` method for `AlternateView` in AE.Net.Mail !

Answer (score 0):

you must set **headers only** to **false**

[image: Mail Sample]

```
 foreach (var item in mm)
            {
                Email myM = new Email();

                myM.Date = item.Date;

                myM.Body = item.Body;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Headers only means it only fetches the email headers, such as from, to, subject, date etc. It does not download the body content or the attachments.