# How to send email using GMAIL API having HTML body + attachment in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gmail-api

```
var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
              {
                  Subject = subject,
                  Body = bodyhtml,
                  From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail")

              };
            foreach (string add in vendorEmailList.Split(','))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
                    continue;

                msg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(add));
            }

            msg.ReplyTo.Add(msg.From); // Bounces without this!!
            msg.ContentType = "text/html";

            ////attachment code

            foreach (string path in attachments)
            {
                var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
                AE.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new AE.Net.Mail.Attachment(bytes, mimeType, Path.GetFileName(path), true);
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            ////end attachment code

            var msgStr = new StringWriter();
            msg.Save(msgStr);

            Message message = new Message();
            message.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString());
            var result = gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").Execute();
```

This code is working without attachment but with attachment instead of attachment directly byte[] is appearing in inbox.

If i remove msg.ContentType = "text/html" this line then it is working but html not rendering in email, appearing as plain text.

I want to send both HTML body and attachment, Please help.

Comment: Could you include the entire message before you encode it? That would be interesting to see. `msgStr.ToString()`

Comment: I tried including entire message without encoding but it is throwing exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = bodyhtml;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            foreach (string add in vendorEmailList.Split(','))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
                    continue;

                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(add));
            }

            foreach (string add in userEmailList.Split(','))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
                    continue;

                mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(add));
            }

            foreach (string path in attachments)
            {
                //var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                //string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(path);//bytes, mimeType, Path.GetFileName(path), true);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            MimeKit.MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mail);

            Message message = new Message();
            message.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(mimeMessage.ToString());
            var result = gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").Execute();
```

I found solution after lot of efforts. Instead of AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage used System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and MimeKit to convert it to raw string. And now html body with attachment is working fine.

Comment: Curious if you've had any issues with this sending out correctly with multiple attachments. It has worked fine for me with a single attachment, then crashes with multiple.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..my code is working for multiple attachments without any issue.

Comment: Works well for me and after days of banging my head on my desk this answer saved my sanity

Answer (score 0):

try adding IsBodyHtml = true

```
 new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
          {
              Subject = subject,
              Body = bodyhtml,
              From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail")
              IsBodyHtml = true
          };
```

Comment: thanks for replay but getting this error 'AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage' does not contain a definition for 'IsBodyHtml

Comment: @user2764660, ahh, sorry, didn't notice AE, I thought System.Net, wait, ill explore on it

Comment: @user2764660: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866096/how-to-get-plaintext-or-html-text-using-ae-net-mail